# How can I not show the content of Disqus

Tags: disqus, github-pages

How can I not show the content of Disqus

[image]

Is it possible? How to do that?

http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax_in_MarkDown.html

This is my github page, sorry forget this important thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to log onto disqus and change your discovery settings to just comments.

1.Login in to disqus
2.Switch to Settings tab
3.Click on Discovery tab
4.Choose the option Just comments
5.Save the settings.

See http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/666278

Comment: Getting `Sorry this page does not exist =(`

Comment: ah, thanks, I solved that, There is a `fontsize=175%` in the body tag, that should be `100%`

Comment: Do you know how to show recent posts in a fixed amount of posts of Jekyll? `<ul class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>`